# locating values in (a very large) pandas dataframe and store to dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, bigdata

I have a very large pandas dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

```
>> df
    "a_1"   "a_2"   "b_1"  "c_2"  ...
"d_1" nan   0.2   nan  nan
"d_2" 0.1   nan   nan   1
"e_1" nan   1     nan  0.2
"e_2" nan   0.05  0.1  0.7
"f_2" 0.2   0.5   0.3  0.9
...
```

Now I am trying to go through a list of tuples which contains some row and col names:

```
t = [("d", "a"), ("d", "c") ...]
```

For example, when `i = ("d", "a")`, I want to find out the values corresponded to `a_1 and a_2`, `d_1 and d_2` and I used the following code to locate the values:

```
s = df.loc[["d_1", "d_2" ], ["a_1", "a_2"]]

# print(s)
#       "a_1"  "a_2"
# "d_1"  nan    0.2
# "d_2   0.1    nan

# convert to list and sort the values
s = s.unstack().reset_index()
s.columns = ["A","B", "Score"]
scores = s.sort_values(by="Score", ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

# pick the index(rank) I want and save the not-nan data to dictionary 
rank = 1
try:
    s = scores.loc[rank,:]
except Exception:
    continue

if str(s.Score) != "nan":
    d[(s.A, s.B)] = s.Score # output dictionary
```

Now the above code works but takes too long, given `len(t) = 28350` and I need to test 150+ sets of parameters. 
One iteration (one set of parameter) takes 3.5mins on the cluster.

I am wondering if there is a better solution to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
d = {}
for row, col in t:
    vals = df.loc[df.index.str.startswith(row),
                  df.columns.str.startswith(col)].stack().dropna()
    if len(vals):
        d[vals.idxmax()] = vals.max()
```